# difference between matrix types 2X3 and 3X2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Consider the following two types of multiplication (Please, Read the whole question):
  $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & x & c \\
    d & e & f \\    
    \end{bmatrix}. \begin{bmatrix}
    g\\
    h\\i
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and,

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & x \\
    d & e  \\    f & g
    \end{bmatrix}. \begin{bmatrix}
    g\\
    h
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, there's a rule in linear algebra that states:
"**$T$ maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^m$ iff the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$**"

Given the rule, the former matrix multiplication we see the fact that the multiplication results in the transformation of  a three dimensional vector into two dimensions.

But, how is this possible, when the columns of the transformation matrix does not span $\mathbb{R}$ because the matrix is linearly dependent??

Similarly, the columns of the transformation matrix of the second multiplication is also not spanning $\mathbb{R}^3$ yet the vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n=2$ is being transformed to $\mathbb{R}^3$. How?

Comment: In your “rule”, replace “to” by “onto”. Then it’s correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case your matrix is $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 3}$ and the induced homomorphism is
$$f_A:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2, \quad f_A(x)=Ax$$

The columns of $A$ are never linearly independent, only $2$ can be since they are in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If two columns are, a $2$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is being mapped onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ and one dimension is "lost information". The vectors "lost" are being mappend into $(0,0)^T$, which is called the kernel of $f_A$ or $A$.

In the second case $B\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 2}$ and
$$f_B: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3,\quad f_B(x)=Bx$$
Here if the columns are linearly independent then the entire space $\mathbb{R}^2$ is mapped onto a 2 dimensional subspace inside $\mathbb{R}^3$. The image is a plane and the rest isn't being "touched" by  $f_B $.

Comment: So, in both the cases, we draw a plane in R^3?

Comment: How can we prove this algebraically?

Comment: By knowing that the matrix is a representation of the underlying homomorphism with respect to a basis. If you treat the lin. Independent columns as the image of a basis then you can prove most of this I suppose. This will become obvious when you learn more linear algebra.

Comment: So, i'd be okay leaving it for now?